# Delete a folder in Win7, folder name is too long and ends with ".."

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems

In

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\lists\Standard
```

i have subfolder called

```
2019-05-26_Mythic Championship Qualifier Barcelona - Szcze...
```

This folder was created by a PHP script and since the folders intended name was too long (i believe) php or windows cut it short, making the last 3 charas into `...`

Using windows explorer as well as command prompt im unable to delete the dir.
In fact, in explorer, im being told `"Could not find this item"` when i try to delete it, even though i can navigate into this (empty) folder.

I really want this folder gone, because its messing up my structure.

What can i possibly do to get rid of this folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Command Prompt, `cd` to the folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\lists`
and use the command `dir /x` to get the 8.3 name of the file,
which may perhaps be `STANDA~1`.

Use the command `del STANDA~1` to delete the file.

Comment: it worked, except it was a FOLDER and i had to use rmdir (it was also called 20FA98~1. thanks.